# differential equations in c++, problems with Runge Kutta's Method

Tags: c++, differential-equations

I wrote a program in c++ that should solve differential equations. The problem is, it seems like it does not work well with ROOT. It compilates fine, but when I execute, this is what I get:

```
*** Break *** segmentation violation



===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
#0  0x00007fc28193984a in __GI___waitpid (pid=7730, stat_loc=stat_loc
entry=0x7ffffe4ae000, options=options
entry=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:31
#1  0x00007fc2818b2ffb in do_system (line=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:148
#2  0x00007fc2831d0954 in TUnixSystem::StackTrace() () from /usr/lib/root/libCore.so
#3  0x00007fc2831d29ec in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals(ESignals) () from /usr/lib/root/libCore.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x0000000000405a8a in Runge_Kutta::Passo(double, VettoreLineare&, double) ()
#6  0x0000000000403b8a in main ()
===========================================================


The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash.
If they do not help you then please submit a bug report at
http://root.cern.ch/bugs. Please post the ENTIRE stack trace
from above as an attachment in addition to anything else
that might help us fixing this issue.
===========================================================
#5  0x0000000000405a8a in Runge_Kutta::Passo(double, VettoreLineare&, double) ()
#6  0x0000000000403b8a in main ()
===========================================================
```

This is my program

equazione_differenziale.c

```
#include "equazione_differenziale.h"

EqDifferenzialeBase :: EqDifferenzialeBase (FunzioneBase* f) {

_f=f;

};

Eulero :: Eulero (FunzioneBase*f) : EqDifferenzialeBase(f) {};

Runge_Kutta :: Runge_Kutta (FunzioneBase* f) : EqDifferenzialeBase(f) {};

VettoreLineare Eulero :: Passo (double t, VettoreLineare& x, double h) {

    VettoreLineare vec(x.GetN());
    vec=x+_f->Eval(t,x)*h;

    return vec;

};

Protone :: Protone (double m, double q, double E0, double f, double lambda){
    _m=m;
    _q=q;
    _E0=E0;
    _f=f;
    _lambda=lambda;
};


VettoreLineare Protone::Eval(double t, const VettoreLineare& v) const{

VettoreLineare y(v.GetN());

    for(int i=0; i<v.GetN()/2; i++){
        y.SetComponent(i, v.GetComponent(v.GetN()/2+i));
        y.SetComponent(i+v.GetN()/2, (-1.)*(_q/_m)*_E0*sin(2*M_PI*(v.GetComponent(i)/_lambda)-2*M_PI*_f*t));
    };

return y;

};

VettoreLineare Runge_Kutta::Passo(double t, VettoreLineare& v, double h){

VettoreLineare k1=_f->Eval(t,v);
VettoreLineare k2=_f->Eval(t+h/2.,v+k1*(h/2.));
VettoreLineare k3=_f->Eval(t+h/2.,v+k2*(h/2.));
VettoreLineare k4=_f->Eval(t+h,v+k3*h);
VettoreLineare y=v+(k1+k2*2.+k3*2.+k4)*(h/6.);

return y;

};
```

equazione_differenziale.h

```
#ifndef equazione_differenziale_h_
#define equazione_differenziale_h_
#include "Vettore.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class FunzioneBase {

public:
virtual VettoreLineare Eval(double t, const VettoreLineare& v) const=0; 

};

class Protone: public FunzioneBase {

private:
double _m,_q,_E0,_f,_lambda;

public:
Protone(double m, double q, double E0, double f, double lambda);
virtual VettoreLineare Eval(double t, const VettoreLineare& v) const;


};




class EqDifferenzialeBase {

protected:
FunzioneBase* _f;

public:
EqDifferenzialeBase (FunzioneBase* f);
virtual VettoreLineare Passo (double t, VettoreLineare& x, double h)=0;
};

class Eulero : public EqDifferenzialeBase {

public:
Eulero (FunzioneBase* f);
virtual VettoreLineare Passo (double t, VettoreLineare& x, double h);

};

class Runge_Kutta: public EqDifferenzialeBase {

protected:
FunzioneBase* _f;

public:
Runge_Kutta (FunzioneBase* f);
virtual VettoreLineare Passo(double t, VettoreLineare& v, double h);
};



#endif
```

Vettore.h

```
#ifndef vettore_h_
#define vettore_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

class Vettore {

protected:
unsigned int _N;
double * _v;
void Quicksort(unsigned int primo, unsigned int ultimo);
void Scambia (int a, int b);

public:
Vettore ();
Vettore (int N);
Vettore (int N, char* nomefile);
Vettore (const Vettore& v);
virtual void SetComponent (int i, double x);
void AddComponent (double x);
double GetComponent (int i) const;
void Print () const;
void Print (char* nomefile) const;
void Sort();
virtual int GetN() const;
Vettore& operator=(const Vettore & vetty);
~Vettore();

};

class VettoreLineare : public Vettore {

protected:


public:
VettoreLineare () : Vettore() {};
VettoreLineare (int N) : Vettore(N) {};
VettoreLineare (int N, char* nomefile) : Vettore(N, nomefile) {};
VettoreLineare (const Vettore& v) : Vettore(v) {};
VettoreLineare operator+(const VettoreLineare& v);
VettoreLineare operator*(double lambda);
VettoreLineare& operator=(const VettoreLineare& v);
virtual int GetN() const;
virtual void SetComponent(int i, double x);

};
```

Vettore.c

```
#include "Vettore.h"

//Default Constructor

Vettore :: Vettore () {

_N=0;
_v=NULL;

};

//N Constructor

Vettore :: Vettore (int N) {

_N=N;
_v=new double [_N];

for (int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    _v[i]=0;

};

//N file-taken constructor

Vettore :: Vettore (int N, char* nomefile) {

_N=N;
_v=new double [_N];

std::ifstream input;
input.open(nomefile);

double dato;

input>>dato;

for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    _v[i]=dato;
    input>>dato;
};

input.close();

};

//Copyconstructor

Vettore :: Vettore (const Vettore& V) {

_N=V.GetN();

_v=new double [_N];

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    _v[i]=V.GetComponent(i);


};

//Destructor

Vettore::~Vettore(){

delete[] _v;

};

//Set Component

void Vettore :: SetComponent (int i, double x) {

if (i>_N) {
std::cout<<"errore!"<<std::endl;
return ;
};


_v[i]=x;

};

//Get Component

double Vettore :: GetComponent (int i) const {

if (i>_N){
std::cout<<"errore!"<<std::endl;
return 0;
};

return _v[i];

};

//Add Component (aggiunge il valore desiderato nella coda del vettore)

void Vettore :: AddComponent (double x) {

double* a=new double [_N+1];

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    a[i]=_v[i];

a[_N]=x;
delete [] _v;
_v=a;

_N=_N+1;


};

//Print

void Vettore :: Print () const {

std::cout<<"Il vettore ha: "<<_N<<" componenti."<<std::endl;

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    std::cout<<_v[i]<<std::endl;

};

//Stampa su file

void Vettore :: Print (char* nomefile) const {
std::ofstream output;
output.open(nomefile);

output<<_N;

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    output<<_v[i]<<std::endl;

output.close();

};


//Get _N

int Vettore :: GetN () const {

return _N;

};

//Operatore di Assegnazione

Vettore & Vettore::operator =(const Vettore& vetty){

if (_v) delete [] _v;

_N=vetty.GetN();
_v=new double [_N];

for(int n; n<_N; n++)
_v[n]=vetty._v[n];

return *this;
};



//Algoritmo Quicksort

void Vettore :: Sort (){
    Quicksort(0,GetN()-1);
};

void Vettore :: Quicksort (unsigned int primo, unsigned int ultimo) {

    if(ultimo-primo<=1){
    if (GetComponent(primo)>GetComponent(ultimo)) Scambia(primo, ultimo);
    return;
    }

    double pivot= GetComponent(int((primo+ultimo)/2));
    unsigned int basso= primo, alto=ultimo;
    while(basso < alto) {

        while (GetComponent(basso)<pivot) basso++;
        while (GetComponent(alto)>pivot) alto--;
        if(basso<alto) { Scambia(basso,alto); basso++;};
    };
    Quicksort(primo, basso-1);
    Quicksort(basso, ultimo);


};

void Vettore :: Scambia(int a, int b){

    double k;
    k=_v[a];
    _v[a]=_v[b];
    _v[b]=k;
};

//Operatore somma fra vettori
VettoreLineare VettoreLineare::operator+ (const VettoreLineare& v){
VettoreLineare sum(v.GetN());

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    sum.SetComponent(i, _v[i]+v.GetComponent(i));

return sum;
};

//Operatore Moltiplicazione scalare

VettoreLineare VettoreLineare::operator* (double lambda){

for(int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    _v[i]=_v[i]*lambda;

return *this;
};

//Operatore Assegnazione

VettoreLineare& VettoreLineare::operator= (const VettoreLineare& k){
if (_v) delete [] _v;
    _N=k.GetN();
    _v=new double [k.GetN()];

for (int i=0; i<_N; i++)
    _v[i]=k.GetComponent(i);

return *this;
};

int VettoreLineare :: GetN() const {
    return _N;
};

void VettoreLineare :: SetComponent(int i, double x) {

_v[i]=x;
};
```

main.c

```
#include "equazione_differenziale.h"
#include "Vettore.h"

#include "iostream"

#include "TGraph.h"
#include "TApplication.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TAxis.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {


//PRIMO PUNTO


//Dichiarazione equazione
Protone* myProt=new Protone (1.67E-27, 1.60E-19, 1.E7, 0.2, 5.E8); 
Runge_Kutta myKutta(myProt);

//Dichiarazione DatiIniziali
VettoreLineare DatiIniziali (2);
DatiIniziali.SetComponent(0, 0);
DatiIniziali.SetComponent(1,1E8);

//dichiarazione tempo
double t_min=0;
double h=1E-12;

//definizione variabili root
TApplication myApp("myApp",0,0);
TGraph* g = new TGraph();

//ciclo 
for(int i=0;i<(1E-7-t_min)/h;i++){
    double x,y;
    x=t_min+i*h;
    DatiIniziali= myKutta.Passo(x, DatiIniziali ,h);
    y=DatiIniziali.GetComponent(0);
    g->SetPoint(i,x,y);
};

//Run grafico
TCanvas *c=new TCanvas("C1","C1",1);
c->cd();
g->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("t[s]");
g->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("x[m]");
g->Draw("AL");
myApp.Run();


return 0;

};
```

The strange thing is that this program works on university computers, but it doesn't on neither of my two computers. I'm thinking this means I installed ROOT badly on both computers, but I sincerely wouldn't know how to proove it.

Comment: *The strange thing is that this program works on university computers, but it doesn't on neither of my two computers.* -- For the C++ language, this is *not* strange at all.  If you've invoked undefined behavior somewhere in your program, there is no guarantee what results you will have when your program runs.

Comment: You did not show the `VettoreLineare` code.  Also -- *it seems like it does not work well with ROOT.* -- No it isn't ROOT, it's your code that is doing something that invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: You should learn how to use a [debugger](https://www.google.ca/?q=c%2B%2B+debugger).

Comment: Thank you both. Naturally I was not assuming the problem could be ascribed to ROOT, sorry if i gave that impression.

Answer (score 1):

You declare

```
class EqDifferenzialeBase {

    protected:
    FunzioneBase* _f;
```

and

```
class Runge_Kutta: public EqDifferenzialeBase {

    protected:
    FunzioneBase* _f;
```

and then do

```
Runge_Kutta :: Runge_Kutta (FunzioneBase* f) : EqDifferenzialeBase(f) {};
```

and then use it as

```
VettoreLineare Runge_Kutta::Passo(double t, VettoreLineare& v, double h){

    VettoreLineare k1=_f->Eval(t,v);
```

From these lines it should be pretty clear what goes wrong and where the `segmentation violation` originates. So get rid of the ghost that shadows the field you really want to use.

And as in the other answer, correct the scalar product of the vector class to the standard of the sum operator.