# Seperating ODE and ODE solver in base and derived classes

Tags: c++, ode, integrator

I think the question a bit long so I think it's better to consider over simplified version of it first:

There is two classes A and B. B inherite from A. There is a member function in B (add) that need to be run using a member function in A.

```cpp
class A;
typedef int(A::*operation)(int c);
typedef void (A::*myfunction)(operation, int);

class A
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;

    int do_something(myfunction f, operation op)
    {
        (this->*f)(op, 1);
    }

    void dummy_name(operation op, int a)
    {
        int c = (this->*op)(a);
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int a, b;

    B(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    int add(int c)
    {
        return a+b+c;
    }

};

int main()
{
    B inst_B(2, 5);
    inst_B.do_something(&A::dummy_name, &B::add);
}
```

```sh
simple.cpp:45:41: error: cannot convert ‘int (B::*)(int)’ to ‘operation’ {aka ‘int (A::*)(int)’}
   45 |     inst_B.do_something(&A::dummy_name, &B::add);
      |                                         ^~~~~~~
      |                                         |
      |                                         int (B::*)(int)
simple.cpp:17:47: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void A::do_something(myfunction, operation)’
   17 |     void do_something(myfunction f, operation op)
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

To write a simple ode solver and to avoid coping integrator inside the class of the model,  for every model including a system of ordinary differential equations, I have seperated the sovler and equations in two class, while model inherite from ode solver.

```cpp
class HarmonicOscillator: public ODE_Sover
```

This is a simplfied example, which contain a few parameters. To avoid passing many parameters and abstraction, I prefered to define the ODE in a class.

I have also used two function templates for derivative (right hand side of the dy/dt = f'(y)) and for integrator (here only euler integrator).
This is what I came up with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class ODE_Solver;
class HarmonicOscillator;
typedef vector<double> dim1;
typedef dim1 (ODE_Solver::*derivative)(const dim1 &, dim1&, const double t);
typedef void (ODE_Solver::*Integrator)(derivative, dim1 &, dim1&, const double t);


class ODE_Solver
{
    public: 
    ODE_Solver()
    {}

    double t;
    double dt;
    dim1 state;
    dim1 dydt;

    void integrate(Integrator integrator, 
                   derivative ode_system, 
                   const int N,
                   const double ti, 
                   const double tf, 
                   const double dt)
    {
        dim1 dydt(N);
        const size_t num_steps = int((tf-ti) / dt);
        for (size_t step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step)
        {   
            double t = step * dt;
            (this->*integrator)(ode_system, state, dydt, t);
            // print state
        }
    }

    void eulerIntegrator(derivative RHS, dim1 &y, dim1 &dydt, const double t)
    {
        int n = y.size();
        (this->*RHS)(y, dydt, t);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            y[i] += dydt[i] * dt;
    }
};

class HarmonicOscillator: public ODE_Solver
{

public:
    int N;
    double dt;
    double gamma;
    string method;
    dim1 state;

    // constructor
    HarmonicOscillator(int N,
                       double gamma,
                       dim1 state
                       ) : N {N}, gamma{gamma}, state{state}
    { }
    //---------------------------------------------------//
    dim1 dampedOscillator(const dim1 &x, dim1&dxdt, const double t)
    {
        dxdt[0] = x[1];
        dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gamma * x[1];

        return dxdt;
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------//

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int N = 2;
    const double gamma = 0.05;
    const double t_iinit = 0.0;
    const double t_final = 10.0;
    const double dt = 0.01;

    dim1 x0{0.0, 1.0};
    HarmonicOscillator ho(N, gamma, x0);
    ho.integrate(&ODE_Solver::eulerIntegrator,
                 &HarmonicOscillator::dampedOscillator, 
                 N, t_iinit, t_final, dt);

    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors:

```sh
example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
example.cpp:93:18: error: cannot convert ‘dim1 (HarmonicOscillator::*)(const dim1&, dim1&, double)’ {aka ‘std::vector<double> (HarmonicOscillator::*)(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, double)’} to ‘derivative’ {aka ‘std::vector<double> (ODE_Solver::*)(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, double)’}
   93 |                  &HarmonicOscillator::dampedOscillator,
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |
      |                  dim1 (HarmonicOscillator::*)(const dim1&, dim1&, double) {aka std::vector<double> (HarmonicOscillator::*)(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, double)}
example.cpp:29:31: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void ODE_Solver::integrate(Integrator, derivative, int, double, double, double)’
   29 |                    derivative ode_system,
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

If I defined the ode at the same class of ode solver it works [link to github](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/ode_solver/blob/master/CPP/02_sho_class.cpp).
So what's your idea?

Comment: You class assembly is too tightly wound, make it less connected, give the solver and the IVP well-separated classes. You can find one such setup in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738918/solving-lorenz-equation, for other approaches that are not just C disguised as C++ see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231161/implementing-modular-runge-kutta-4th-order, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965829/runge-kuttas-method

Comment: You could also study the interfaces in boost-odeint or in the julia package differentialequations.jl for inspiration, but in these extended functionality is factored in, such as step-size control, dense output, event-action mechanisms, ... Not all of that complexity is needed for fixed-step explicit Runge-Kutta methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I already looked at boost.odeint, but I want to try this approach as well for it's experience. odeint need to pass the parameters to the derivative for each call.  I also need to define some DDE solver that odeint does not support. It's just a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First, when you want to pass arbitrary functions as arguments to other functions, consider using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Second, inheritance should be used to declare ["is-a" relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Since a harmonic oscillator is *not* an ODE solver, don't use inheritance for this. There's also not a "has-a" relationship (so [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is also not appropriate), instead the solver *acts on* a given function, so the most appropriate thing to do is to pass the harmonic oscillator as a parameter to the solver function.

An example of what the code might look like:

```
class HarmonicOscillator {
    ...
public:
    ...
    double operator()(double t) {
        ...
        return /* value at time t */;
    }
};

double integrate(std::function<double(double)> func, double start, double end, double dt) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (double t = start; t < end; t += dt)
        sum += func(t) * dt;

    return sum;
}
```

And then you just call it like so:

```
HarmonicOscillator ho(...);
auto result = integrate(ho, t_iinit, t_final, dt);
```

The above might not do exactly what you want, but that is the structure of the code I think you should aim for.

If you want to be able to handle function that not only take a `double` and return a `double`, but arbitrary types, you could make `integrate()` a template:

```
template <typename Function, typename T>
auto integrate(Function func, T start, T end, T dt) {
    decltype(func(start)) sum{};

    for (T t = start; t < end; t += dt)
        sum += func(t) * dt;

    return sum;
}
```

This works if you create proper types for the input and output values that support arithmetic operations, it won't work with your `dim1`. I recommend you try to find a library that implements mathematical vector types, like [Eigen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigen_(C%2B%2B_library)) for example.

Comment: Thank you.  Two main goal for me is to avoid writing integrators (ODE, DDE, SDE, ... solvers) for each model and ease of passing multiple parameters (here only one is present :gamma, sometime up to 20). I think about it.

Comment: @Abolfazl : But that is what the ODE function class is about, with its () operator. You can put all the parameters as data members of that class, set their values via constructor or specific setter functions, and have the standard interface for the ODE function in the () operator. /// ODE, DDE and SDE need different interfaces on a conceptual level, there is no need to force them into a uniform format.